# BigDecimal 1.0E+8 / 100000000 with ROUND_HALF_UP is 0

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal, divide

Can some one explain why I get 0 as result for the first line?

```
System.out.println((new BigDecimal("1.0E+8")).divide(new BigDecimal(100000000), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
System.out.println((new BigDecimal("1.0E+8")).subtract(BigDecimal.ONE).divide(new BigDecimal(100000000), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));

0E+7
1
```

Comment: Why is it "0E+7" and not "0"?

Comment: @user2864740 That *is* the output, but I think OP expected `1`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It all has to do with the *scales* of the `BigDecimal`s involved.

When you specify exponential format in the [constructor that takes a `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-java.lang.String-), the scale may be negative.  This indicates that the significant digits don't extend all the way down to unity.

```
BigDecimal oneEPlus8 = new BigDecimal("1.0E+8");
System.out.println(oneEPlus8.scale());
```

This outputs `-7`.

Using the [constructor that takes an `int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-int-) yields a scale of `0`.

```
BigDecimal oneHundredMillion = new BigDecimal(100000000);
System.out.println(oneHundredMillion.scale());
```

This outputs `0`.

When you [`divide` `BigDecimal`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-int-), the quotient takes the scale of the object on which `divide` is called.  So, the quotient's scale is also `-7`.  The result was calculated to be `1`, but in the scale of `-7`, rounding only gives two options: `0` or `10000000`, so `ROUND_HALF_UP` rounds to `0`, giving output of `0E+7`.

When you [`subtract` `BigDecimal`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#subtract-java.math.BigDecimal-), the difference takes the maximum of the scales of the numbers being subtracted.  So, the difference's scale is `0`.  The result is calculated to be `1`, and the scale of `0` doesn't force a rounding here.  The output is `1`.

To get the result `1` without having to subtract `1`, you can subtract `0`, or you can call `setScale(0)` on `oneEPlus8`.

```
oneEPlus8 = oneEPlus8.setScale(0);
System.out.println(oneEPlus8.divide(oneHundredMillion, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

This outputs:

```
1
```

As an aside, you can use [`divide(BigDecimal, RoundingMode)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-java.math.RoundingMode-) to divide specifying a `RoundingMode` enum instead of the older `int` constants.